# How to tell if a vector lies in a given vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a vector $\vec{v}\in \mathbb{R}^n$ and a vector space $V$ that is an $n-1$ dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$.  Is there a nice way to tell if $\vec{v} \in V$?  I know that this would mean $\vec{v}$ is a linear combination of the basis vectors of $V$, but I don't know:

a) How do I check to make sure that there is a linear combination for a given $\vec{v}$?

b) Is it possible to restrict the components of $\vec{v}$ such that the linear combination always exists, and if so, how? (this is what I'm really looking for, a restriction on the components of $\vec{v}$.

Comment: What does it mean that $V$ spans $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$, or that $V$'s basis vectors come from $\mathbb{R}^n$? Do you really mean that $V$ is an $n-1$ dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: Yes, I'll edit the question

Comment: Create a matrix of the $(n-1)$ basis vectors of $V + v$,  If the determinant = 0, then $v \in V.$

Comment: is there any way to do it without computing the determinant?  I would need to solve a high order polynomial to do so, right?  Since there is no closed form solution for that in general, that is not *ideal*.  However, it sounds like this question actually reduces to solving such a polynomial, doesn't it?

Comment: No, if you have a $n \times n$ matrix of numbers then you can compute its determinant in $O(n^3)$ time using Gaussian elimination. Note that Gaussian elimination itself is a slightly more direct, and significantly more general, approach. Specifically, you can take the $n-1$ basis vectors of $V$, augment them with the vector $v$, and then run Gaussian elimination to see if the resulting linear system is consistent.

Comment: What do you mean by x? Your notation is confusing,I'd rewrite the question so it's clear what elements of V we're talking about.

Comment: Sorry, I've been mixing my notation. So that answers part a nicely. But what about part b? I want to restrict the components of $\vec{v}$ so that the system is consistent.

Comment: If you have an $n-1$ dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$, the condition to be in that space is a single linear equation, namely that the vector be perpendicular to the null space of $A^T$. (This is part of the "four fundamental subspaces theorem".) You can again get that equation from Gaussian elimination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let H is a matrix, which columns span the vector space V; $v \in V$ iff there exists a vector a such that $v = H a$. Suppose that orthonormal basis of V is available, i.e. columns of H are orthonormal. Then
$$v = H a \Rightarrow H^Tv = H^THa = a$$
and $v \in V \Leftrightarrow v - HH^Tv = 0$. This is also the fastest test for $v \in V$ if othonormal basis of V is available.

If orthonormal basis is not available, then

1. you may create orthonormal basis from H by applying Gram Schmidt orthogonalization process to H (or compute QR factorization of H) and apply test above.
2. use the fact, that $v \in V \Leftrightarrow rank(H) = rank([H,v])$ and compute LU factorization of $[H,v]$. If all diagonal elements of U factor are nonzero, then $v\not\in V$, otherwise $v\in V$. If $dim(V) = n-1$ then this test is equivalent to $v \in V \Leftrightarrow det([H,v]) = 0$.

Answer to the question b depends on modifications of v, that are allowed; it is not clear what you mean. If you are looking for a a scalar $\alpha$, such that $v + \alpha z \in V$ for a given vector z, then such problem has solution iff $v = [H,z]\times b$ for some b.